# WPF order listbox items

Tags: wpf

How do I order my items bound from model to the list box.

I have defined model that is:

```
public ObservableCollection<NotificationItem> Classes:
```

I need to order it by id which is assigned to every notification item.

at present I have definition:

```
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Classes, Source={StaticResource model}}"
                   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
DataContext="{Binding}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

where I have reference of model:

```
<Model:ClassModel x:Key="model" />
```

Update:

where initialisation  of the model is done by

```
 try
            {
                this.notifierModel = this.Resources["model"] as ClassModel;

                this.classController.Initialize(this.notifierModel);

            }
            catch
            {
             // todo: handle exception
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either order your collection directly on your model (data context), or create a custom [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx) and bind your ListBox to that instead.

Answer (score 3):

Where you set up `Classes` you need to have:

```
Classes = new ObservableCollection(results.OrderBy(i => i.Id));
```

instead of just:

```
Classes = new ObservableCollection(results);
```

assuming that `results` is list of data returned by your query.

Comment: Chris, i cannot make your solution working. i think that its because the list is from beginning empty. And this solution will work only for allready completed collection. Is that right or am i missing something?